# How to identify an entity in ER diagram

Tags: database, database-design

I have a usecase which describes like : 
"Candidates register their details like personal, academics, skill set and experience."

I have selected Candidate as an entiry , so does registration form become an entity ? , or all those details would be attributes for Candidate entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, You would have an Entity called RegistraionEvent, which will have the Registration details such as Date, and Status of Registration. If the Candidate can have more than one Registration, then you would have another entity called Candidate_registration in Physical model. In Logical model, it would just show up as a many-to-many relationship.